# TypeError within f-string expression - 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, typeerror, f-string

I am getting an error when I try to compose a string using f-string syntax in Python 3.7.

My code is the following:

```
i = 1

site_id= 0
meter = 0
model_id = i
target_name = 'log1p_meter_reading_corrected2'

f'model_site_id_{str(site_id)}_meter_{str(meter)}_{target_name}_model_id_{str(model_id)}_11_12_19.hdf5'
```

which returns the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-1ebe1c78d868> in <module>
      6 target_name = 'log1p_meter_reading_corrected2'
      7 
----> 8 f'model_site_id_{str(site_id)}_meter_{str(meter)}_{target_name}_model_id_{str(model_id)}_11_12_19.hdf5'

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What creates the error and how should I correct my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) you don't need to wrap the variable with `str()`. The following should work:

```
f'model_site_id_{site_id}_meter_{meter}_{target_name}_model_id_{model_id}_11_12_19.hdf5'
```

However, your code should technically work fine, the `str()` calls are just redundant - you have probably reassigned the reserved keyword `str` at some point by doing something like:

```
str = 'test'
```

Now, if we do

```
>>> str(site_id)
```

We get

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```